# What is my error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Input:

```
var myName = 'Sophia';
console.log('Hello my name is', + myName + '.');
```

Output:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: The code shown does not throw an Unexpected identifier error.  Check the line the error refers to again and post that code

Answer (score 3):

You can use a comma in `console.log()` arguments to separate values/expressions that need to be logged into their own individual statements, but because you also have `+` it causes an error because `+` with string operands mean concatenation and you aren't concatenating anything to it in that section.

You can either remove the comma or remove the two `+` symbols.

```js
var myName = 'Sophia';
console.log('Hello my name is ' + myName + '.'); // No comma - one expression to evaluate
console.log('Hello my name is',  myName, '.');   // With commas - 3 expressions to evaluate
console.log('Hello my name is',  myName + '.');  // Combination - 2 expressions to evaluate
```

Comment: Well, either the comma or the plusses and the period -  `console.log('Hello my name is ', myName');` is also acceptable. I think OP just mixed the two together.

Comment: Comma is not an unexpected identifier there, it would just mean the console will log two different arguments, `"Hello my name is"` and then `NaN.` NaN will happen due to `+myName` number coercion then concatenation with the period

Comment: Your answer is not producing expected output. Why `,` should be removed? What if the requirement is to have output with comma before name? It is better to put comma inside first string. Please check my answer.

Comment: @VicJordan Who says my answer is not producing the expected output? There is no indication that the comma should be part of the string of output, especially since (with this particular string), it would be grammatically incorrect and make the sentence make no sense. Obviously, if the comma was supposed to be in the output it should be inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

The ',' should be removed.

Regarding how to use '+' to concatenate strings, you can refer to Long literal strings section in this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

```js
var myName = 'Sophia'; 
console.log('Hello my name is ' + myName + '.');
```

Comment: Why `,` should be removed? What if the requirement is to have output with comma before name?

Answer (score 0):

The comma is not allowed in between string and concatenation if you really need then you just use ES6 template Strings can contain placeholders for string substitution using the ${ } syntax, as demonstrated below:

```
var myName = 'Sophia';
console.log(`Hello my name is , ${myName} .`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have comma in your output then you can do it like below

```js
var myName = 'Sophia';
console.log('Hello my name is, ' + myName + '.');
```

**BUT** if comma is added by mistake then simply remove `,` and there will be expected output. Example below:

```js
var myName = 'Sophia';
console.log('Hello my name is ' + myName + '.');
```